# How to assign Class to data retrieved from Firestore in Firebase functions(typescript)?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm retriving data from firestore and at the same times I'm trying to assign class to data that is recived but that does not work, what is the correct way of doing that?

```
async function getAcceptedShifts(monthKey: string):Promise<Shift[]> {
   return (await db.collection('companies').doc(companyIdd)
          .collection('months')
          .doc(monthKey).collection('acceptedShifts')
          .get()).docs.map(val=>{
                let s = val.data as Shift
                return s;
  })
}
```

and the Shift class:

```
class Shift{

   changeDate?: Date;
   startTime?: { year: number, month: number
            , day: number, hour: number, minute: number };
   endTime?: { year: number, month: number
          , day: number, hour: number, minute: number };
   employeeId?:string
}
```

Comment: `val.data` is a function, not an object.  Call it with parenthesis: `val.data()`.  https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.13.x/DocumentSnapshot#data

Answer (score 0):

well the correct way is:

```
return val.data()
```

-so the problem was missing paranteses! -.-